# anyway to tell which cloud provider current k8s cluster is running at?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm writing a k8s operator, with the knowledge of current cloud provider the k8s is currently running on, I can do some platform-specific tasks for users, such as prepare some default storage classes for users.

but how can an operator running in the k8s cluster know it is GCP or AWS?

After scanning through the APIs, the cloud provider leaves some clues here and there, for example, for the GKE cluster I am running now, it has an API named: `/apis/nodemanagement.gke.io/v1alpha1`

but I think it's a little bit too hack, and wonder if there is any more formal way to get this info.

Comment: you can add `--cloud-provider=<gce/aws>` flag in your operator

Comment: would love to know the reason for the down votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not exposed in a consistent way. You should have the use put it in their config file or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it's not consistent. When the configuration is added by default to kubectl, you have these patterns:

```
> kubectl config current-context

# For GCP
> gke_gbl-imt-homerider-basguillaueb_europe-west1-b_my-first-cluster-1

# For AWS
> arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:306974639454:cluster/demo-knative
```

You can also rename the config is you prefer your own pattern.